# Concurrent quicksort

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

So I've implemented a quicksort algorithm in go. I tested it with `go test`, works perfectly well. Now I wanted to make it concurrent and check the differences in computational times. Algorithm looks like this:

```
package mysort

import (
    "math/rand"
)

// ConcurrentPartition - ConcurrentQuicksort function for partitioning the array (randomized choice of a pivot)
func ConcurrentPartition(A []int, p int, r int) int {
    index := rand.Intn(r-p) + p
    pivot := A[index]
    A[index] = A[r]
    A[r] = pivot
    x := A[r]
    j := p - 1
    i := p
    for i < r {
        if A[i] <= x {
            j++
            tmp := A[j]
            A[j] = A[i]
            A[i] = tmp
        }
        i++
    }
    temp := A[j+1]
    A[j+1] = A[r]
    A[r] = temp
    return j + 1
}

// ConcurrentQuicksort - a concurrent version of a quicksort algorithm
func ConcurrentQuicksort(A []int, p int, r int) {
    if p < r {
        q := ConcurrentPartition(A, p, r)
        ConcurrentQuicksort(A, p, q-1)
        ConcurrentQuicksort(A, q+1, r)
    }
}
```

Every `ConcurrentQuicksort` is actuall independent by default as its build on `divide and conquer` philosophy. So the only thing I did was adding `go` keyword before every recursive call, like this:

```
go ConcurrentQuicksort(A, p, q-1)
go ConcurrentQuicksort(A, q+1, r)
```

I didnt't work. As I've seen it just took a array and didn't even once called the recursive quicksort. So I've added `time` import and this line:

`time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)` (thats after `if`)

And it worked. So I guess it needed time to complete all the operations. How can I now make it without waiting? Should I use channel, or maybe call the functions differently?

@Edit Added this:

```
func ConcurrentQuicksort(A []int, p int, r int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    if p < r {
        q := ConcurrentPartition(A, p, r)
        wg.Add(2)
        go ConcurrentQuicksort(A, p, q-1, wg)
        go ConcurrentQuicksort(A, q+1, r, wg)
    }
}
```

Comment: You are just launching the goroutines, but you'll have to wait until both are finished with their work: The (sub)array is _not_ sorted until both goroutines finish. No magic here.

Comment: In your base case, you would need to tell the WaitGroup that you are done waiting.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `sync` package here. Creating a [WaitGroup](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) will actually do not go further down the thread until all of your go routines are actually done. It has pretty trivial interface. Here is the example of usage.

```
func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(index int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            fmt.Println("I'm done and my index is", index)
        }(i)
    }

    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Println("This message is actually printed after all goroutines are done")
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but then how can I maintain the `defer wg.Done()` if I have recursive calls

Comment: You can pass reference to `wg` into your recursively called function as a parameter

Comment: Then I get: `fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!`, updated the code I added

Comment: Could you please provide example of test data

Comment: I test this by this: `// Main function
func main() {
 a := []int{6, 7, 2, 9, 1, 8, 27, 21, 53738, 11, 6432, 7234, 22, 56, 291, 2588}
 var wg sync.WaitGroup
 mysort.ConcurrentQuicksort(a, 0, len(a)-1, &wg)
 wg.Wait()
 fmt.Println(a)
}
`

Comment: @Frynio the code that would work for you could be found here https://play.golang.org/p/Z-UCHuFzn8. However, I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to achieve - non-concurrent sorting would slower here